# Form elements and logic within a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a number of forms on my site, all of which are vastly different. There will however be an element which is shared by all - a few text boxes and a validation message depending on the input.

I'm using asp.net MVC3 and in the interests of code-reuse, I'd like to put this shared element into a partial view which will be included in every form. This partial view will have to perform the logic to check the input and display a validation message accordingly.

Does anyone have any pointers on how I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use a PartialView, I'd rather go with an EditorTemplate/DisplayTemplate for a sub view class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a ViewModel for your common view Say

```
public class CommonViewModel
{
    public bool IsValid {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}

}
```

Now Say for some other ViewModel

```
public class MyOtherViewModel
{
    public  CommonViewModel CommonViewModel {get;set;}
    //Other Properties here


}
```

Now from MyOtherView.cshtml you can render the partial view easily, passing the values from main view

```
@model MyOtherViewModel
@Html.Partial("commonView",Model.CommonViewModel)
```

I hope this should help you to start with.

cheers

Comment: +1: I agree with having Nested Models, but in place of the PartialView, I think it's better to define a custom EditorTemplate/DisplayTemplate.

Comment: Thanks Guys, but what difference EditorTemplate will make in this case.

Comment: well on the surface EditorTemplates may seem just like partial views, but that's only on the surface, semantically the Template is powerfull and can be used by the framework (e.g. you just put an @EditorFor(Model)) and leave to the templates all the work. As usual it depends on specific scenarios (like 99.99% of things in IT).

Comment: Another pro (or con) of the EditorTemplate is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610603/an-asp-net-mvc-gotcha-frustrated (see Scott Ripley's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a rough code, please correct accordingly.
Use a Parital View and write code as below.

@Html.BeginForm('actionname',controller)
{
@Html.TextBox('abc')

}

then create a method in your controller like

[Post]
Public ActionResult ActionName()
{

}

put this partialview in any of you page.