# An ASP.NET MVC Gotcha? Frustrated

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with ASP.NET MVC html helpers like TextBoxFor(), HiddenFor(), etc. If I have a model such as Employee with the string member Name and execute Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name), is it wrong for me to assume that ASP.NET MVC **will always use** the value in the Employee's Name? Because it doesn't. ASP.NET will override that binding and use what's in the POST.

For exmaple let's say I have the following code:

**Model**

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public List<Employee> Employees { set; get; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
         public ActionResult Company(string Name)
        {
            return View(new Company { 
                Name = Name, 
                Employees = new List<Employee> { 
                    new Employee { Name = "Ralph" }, 
                    new Employee { Name = "Joe" } } 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Home/Company.cshtml**

```
@using MvcApplication2.Models;
@model Company


<h2>Company's Name: @Model.Name</h2>
@foreach (Employee emp in Model.Employees)
{

    Html.RenderPartial("Employee", emp);
}
```

**Home/Employee.cshtml**

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Employee
<b>Employee's Name: </b> @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name);
```

When I hit the relative url "Home/Company?Name=MSFT", I expected Employee.cshtml to render "Ralph" and "Joe" in the textboxes but instead it renders MSFT for both textboxes. What do I have to do so that "Ralph" and "Joe" shows up in the textboxes? Do i have to make sure that my POST and GET variables never conflict in all layers of my view models (in this case the Company and Employee classes)? This seems silly. There's got to be an easy workaround, right?

Here's a screenshot of the result:
[image]

Comment: Strange, I've tried your code and it works perfect. Please make sure that your don't mix models.

Comment: Im very sure that i did not mix up my models. I'll upload a sample project demonstrating this behaviour if someone isn't able to reproduce it.

Comment: Could you try changing the name of the `Name` property on one of your two model types - for example, use `FullName` on the employee? As @Kate noted, it is likely that you're mixing your models somewhere, and doing a rename on one of the properties might help show where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### HtmlHelper methods and ModelState

An important thing to understand with MVC HtmlHelper methods:
They always look at `ModelState` first, `value` second, `ViewData` third.

The `ModelState` is important, because it contains the user-submitted values.  If a page fails validation, the `ModelState` is used to store the previous values and error messages.

If you want to POST a form, and if everything is valid, you want to show the form again, you either have to:

- Redierect from the POST to the GET (following the PRG Pattern)
- Clear the ModelState: `ModelState.Clear();`

### EditorFor vs RenderPartial

Another important thing to mention is the difference between `EditorFor/DisplayFor` vs `RenderPartial`.

When you use `EditorFor/DisplayFor` for an item (such as `.EditorFor(m => m.Person)`), it adds a sort-of "namespace" to the template of `"Person"` so that the sub-controls will have a unique name.  For example, in the template, `.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name)` will render something like `<input name="Person.Name" ...`.

However, when you use `RenderPartial`, no such namespace is created.  Therefore, `.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name)` will render `<input name="Name" ...`, which will not be unique if you have multiple editors.

Comment: Thanks. Using either EditorFor()/DisplayFor() was key to prevent unwanted model binding in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this behavior might be frustrating, and that it might seem illogical.  However, your frustration is a result of not fully understanding how Model binding works.  There is a logical chain of events that occur during binding, and if you understand how it works then it will help avoid these kinds of mistakes.

As Scott mentioned, MVC will always look in ModelState first.  You can avoid this problem by making sure you don't have any querystring parameters that have the same name as any properties in your model.